# Retrieving Activity Feed: Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

After doing a bit of research it seems Firebase isn’t very well suited to perform a task such as activity feed, being there is no IN operator like MySQL has.

My question is, wouldn’t activity feed become quite expensive or time consuming to carry out with Firebase since you would have to make a loop and query each individual User ID in an array of the user ID’s of the people someone follows to find recent posts that those people have made.

I couldn’t find much information on the cons of using Firebase for a feed model. Maybe I am misunderstanding how Firebase operates but this just seems very inefficient on a large scale. Would it be probable to use MySQL to carry out this task?

Thanks,

Troy

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: That said, if you come from a background with relational databases, Firebase's NoSQL data model may take some getting used to. But assumptions about its scalability are mostly based on that lack of experience. Once you adapt to the NoSQL data model of Firebase Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore, they can scale to quite extreme number of concurrent reads. I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Comment: And Todd's new video series for Cloud Firestore: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_hR4K4auoQ and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ofux_4c94FI

Comment: Also recommended is having a look at Firefeed.io, a (quite old, but still relevant) sample app for Firebase Realtime Database that deals with feeds. https://firefeed.io/about.html

Comment: Very good information, thank you. I will look into the video series ASAP. I was on track with doing something similar to the firefeed link you provided but I guess what I’m still unclear on is the pricing. Wouldn’t writing the post into the feed of every follower be extremely costly on large scale? Where pay as you go is $0.18/100k writes.

Comment: That applies to Firestore. If you think that affects your use-case, definitely do a price-comparison with the Realtime Database, which has a different pricing model.

Comment: Wow, yea I see the difference now. Thank you so much, sorry for the trouble.

Comment: No trouble whatsoever. I copied most of the details in an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you come from a background with relational databases, Firebase's NoSQL data model may take some getting used to. Most assumptions about its limited scalability are based on that lack of experience. Once you adapt to the NoSQL data model of Firebase Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore, they can scale to quite extreme number of concurrent reads.

I recommend:

- reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).
- watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) (made for the Realtime Database, but a lot also applies to Cloud Firestore).
- watching Todd's new video series for Cloud Firestore ([episode 1](https://youtube.com/watch?v=v_hR4K4auoQ) and [episode 2](https://youtube.com/watch?v=Ofux_4c94FI)).

Comment: This does not answer the question